# How do you actually use FolderPicker in a UWP to grant IO access

Tags: c#, uwp, file-access

I'm trying to do some generic database stuff with a UWP at a directory the user specifies, but I am having a nightmare with the access rights.

I've read everything I can find about the folder picker and I'm still not getting gifted access. My understanding was once the user picked a folder I could use that folder as I pleased, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

- Is it as simple as I can't use Directory commands from a UWP?
- Is there any documentation to show how to use FolderPicker Queries?
- Am I going to have the same nightmare when I try an SQL connection?

```
    private Windows.Storage.StorageFolder _fileAccess = null;

    private async void Btn_Browse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FolderPicker picker = new FolderPicker
        {
            ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List,
            SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.ComputerFolder
        };
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

        _fileAccess = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
        if (_fileAccess == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Tbx_Directory.Text = _fileAccess.Path;

        StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.
        AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", _fileAccess);


        string[] dataBases = Directory.GetFiles(_fileAccess.Path, @"*.db");

        foreach (string file in dataBases ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>())
        { 
            LBxV_Databases.Items.Add(file);
        }
    }
```

I get the access violation on the Directory use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `FutureAccessList`, this is a great choice, but there is a problem with the way you use it.

Here is the way to get the saved `StorageFolder`:

```cs
public async Task<StorageFolder> GetFolderFromAccessList(string tokenName)
{
    var folder = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync(tokenName);
    return folder;
}
```

With the `FolderPicker`, you can get the `StorageFolder` object. But saving this object to the `FutureAccessList` does not allow you to access the folder with the path. You can only get the saved folder object by the **Token** which save in the `FutureAccessList`.

Because the UWP application is a sandbox application, when you access the database, I recommend that you save the database file in the application's local directory, such as `ApplicationData.LocalFolder`. You can't directly access the external file without adding special Capability.

You can find an official application example provided by Microsoft [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/cdfd8ef6b38a710eb5e85c776a48c8369b4c74de/Samples/FileAccess), which demonstrates how to access files/folders persistently.

Best regards.